# In what kind of use are Servicestack's sessions in a multi-server environment scalable?

Tags: scalability, servicestack

When a user is authenticated, the session is stored using the defined ICacheclient, which can be memory, memcached or redis.
If I use two web server, I suppose the session is only populated on the server where the authentication was done, am I right ?

Do I have to use sticky session in this scenario (memory cache client) ?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, use the `MemoryCacheClient` to keep all Session information in the memory on a single web server. Use **Redis** or **Memcached** (which are the fastest distributed cache server options) if you want to share Session info across multiple load-balanced app servers. Each options are extremely high-performant - it just depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 2):

We have a pair of servers delivering our web app and can scale as we need.  We use REDIS to maintain a clients authentication status through the ICacheclient interface.  To enable easy testing on the build machine we switch between redis and memcached based on whether a debugger is attached.  Our Apphost.cs has this:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());        
}
else
{
    container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager(AppConfig.REDISUrl + ":" + AppConfig.REDISPort));
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => (ICacheClient)c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient());
}
```

The built in authenication methods just work with whatever the ICacheClient is set to as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization)